# Handle offline firestore document upload

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I upload a document without internet connection, my loader screen didn't hide because firestore doesn't pass through onSuccessListener or onFailureListener and I can't call my "hideProgress()" method. But if I close the app and then open again it, the new document is added correctly to the database. How should I handle the NO internet connection?

That's my code:

```
   fun updateExercise(userId: String, documentId: String, exercise: DiaryRequest) {
    FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true)
    try {

        db.collection("utenti")
            .document(userId)
            .collection("diario")
            .document(documentId)
            .set(exercise, SetOptions.merge())
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                mView.onUploadCompleted()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                mView.onUploadCompleted()
            }
    }catch (e: UnknownHostException){
        mView.onUploadCompleted()
    }
}
```

This is a log:

```
   2019-05-22 15:23:14.880 21568-21615/com.energym.app.energympalestre I/Firestore: (19.0.0) [WriteStream]: (44c5c29) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:331)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:517)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:299)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:214) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:517) 
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:299) 
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:214) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
}.
```

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why you have this behaviour. For your issue, you can use `addSnapshotListener` instead.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I already gave a reading at some similar question, but the only solution I found is to add a connection listener...why I can't handle the exception in the log?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The code above, trying to catch exception like "UnknowHostException","JavaRuntimeException" and "FirebaseFirestoreException" but it didn't work. I'm not able to call mView.onUploadCompleted() to hide the progress bar.